# A combination of a singular and plural noun in a question

Tags: grammatical-number, questions

> Which country or countries do you think they are?

Is that sentence grammatically correct?
It'd be incredibly awkward to say

> Which country or countries do you think it is or they are?

Comment: Can you provide more context? When you get to a place like this, it's usually time to write yourself out of it: *Which country or countries can you identify as [being involved]?*

Comment: You don't need to say "country or countries". Just say "countries", it's OK if the answer is just one.

Comment: In a conversation with a seasoned Anglophone, as Barmar advises, 'countries' will almost always elicit a singular or plural reply as the addressee deems appropriate. In a test, candidates could well pick up an unintended miscue; I'd rephrase: << List all those countries, if any, you think are involved. >>

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to leave the number of countries open. For example, if you are asking someone which countries speak Tamil, you don't want to ask "Which country speaks Tamil?", because that would imply only one country speaks Tamil, and you don't want to say "Which countries speak Tamil?", because if your listener thought of only saying Sri Lanka, they'll now be prompted to add India as well.

However, English doesn't have a way of satisfying your requirement. In the above example, you have to use the second question and accept that you've given the listener a clue.